# Mp2307 maximum duty cycle in the datasheet

Tags: dc-dc-converter

[MP2307 datasheet](https://www.monolithicpower.com/DesktopModules/DocumentManage/API/Document/GetDocument?id=583) says on the second page: Maximum Duty Cycle when FB=1.00V, 90%. A few lines up says the FB between from 0.900V to 0.950V.

So why calculate with FB=1.00V, if the feedback voltage is ~0.925V?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 1V level is a test set point to force it into max duty cycle but not high enough to put it into the over voltage mode.

Note 0.925 is the internal reference voltage it regulates to, not the actual max on the FB pin.

Answer (score 0):

This defines the OVP headroom for V regulation at Vfb=1 DMAX=90% so there is still 10% MIN margin for linear regulation. If Vfb exceeds 20% it shuts off the clock indicating some excessive kickback being sensed, which creates a nonlinear disturbance.

from spec

> When the FB pin voltage exceeds 20% ( or 1.11V) of the nominal regulation value of 0.925V, the over voltage comparator is tripped and the COMP pin and the SS pin are discharged to GND, forcing the high-side switch off.